# How would civilians send snacks to the ISS crew?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, procedure, food

Today I saw a video in which ESA astronaut Samantha Cristoforetti [teaches us how to make pitas in space, and invites us to try to make them at home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4exaXdPKS3Y). I understand that much of the food on the ISS is freezed dried. My sister and I enjoy freeze-dried mangos and would like to send some to the ISS crew to taste. **Who should I contact to propose to send the astronauts our favorite snack?**

I feel that this question is related to space exploration as one of the purposes of the ISS is to **establish a human presence off-planet**, or to practice doing so. All permanent human dwellings have mail service, even if it is irregular or not periodic. Therefore, to normalize the ISS to a normal human dwelling it should be expected that people would be able to send packages there, even under scrutiny. **Realizing this would be a terrific step forward in man's conquest of space.**

*Note that this question was translated into English by my father, who is the one typing it. I'm eight years old and [I don't use SE unsupervised](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/move-a-question-to-a-new-user).*

Comment: Pretty sure the amount of postage you'll need will amount to covering your packet in multiple layers of stamps :-)

Comment: By the time you get enough stamps you'll need more stamps for the weight of the postage, which will require more stamps... It's like a reverse rocket equation!

Comment: The next batch of repair parts for the ISS should include some Swedish Fish. Congrats on the question, and keep asking and seeking knowledge  for the rest of your life!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, you would want to contact *NASA* (or another one of the participating space agencies) to request sending anything to or from the International Space Station.

You could try contacting a former astronaut via social media (e.g. Cmdr. Chris Hadfield, who has a [lively Twitter account](https://twitter.com/cmdr_hadfield)). Even though an astronaut (probably) wouldn't have the authority to make this kind of decision, they would very likely know who to contact.

You could try contacting the Student Spaceflight Experiments Program ([link](http://ssep.ncesse.org/)). While your idea isn't an *experiment*, this is an open channel for collecting students' ISS-related ideas and putting them into action!

My *guess* is that the officials managing the ISS crew would want to send food that is professionally prepared for the ISS crew...but who knows!  :-)

Comment: If you are from Europe, _Andreas Mogensen_ is soon going to ISS, you _could_ ask him to take something for the trip!

Comment: Id have to imagine there are some controls around this. Imagine, despite having good intentions, you give the entire ISS crew extreme diherrea-- the worst space outbreak in history.